# Удаление символов из текста

Tags: ruby

Есть некий текст:

```
Здравствуйте, Helpdesk.
   © 
 ™
С уважением,
```

Каким образом средствами ruby можно его отчистить от всех лишних символов (типа смайлов и прочего), чтобы в итоге остался только чистый текст (Буквы, знаки препинания, пробелы, переносы строк, табуляция)?

Answer (score 4):

[Метод `String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-delete) существует примерно для этого: он принимает на вход паттерны для символов и вырезает из строки те символы, что подходят под **все сразу**.

```
"hello".delete "l","lo"        #=> "heo"
"hello".delete "lo"            #=> "he"
"hello".delete "aeiou", "^e"   #=> "hell"
"hello".delete "ej-m"          #=> "ho"
```

- `j-m` это буквы `jklm`, это диапазон
- `^` в начале паттерна это отрицание, чтобы под паттерн подошло "всё кроме"
- порядок символов в паттерне никак не учитывается

Имейте в виду, он не деструктивный, он вернёт *копию* вашей строки. Преобразовать "на месте" нужно методом `delete!`, аргументы идентичны.

Вам остаётся только сформулировать определение "чистого текста" (исключать из него смайлики опасно ) в виде паттернов для этой функции.

Comment: а чем опасно исключать смайлики? Вся проблема в том, что текст с данными символами не вставляется в базу: _Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x89 \xC2...' for column 'subject

Comment: @S.Ivanov пользователи будут против, вот почему `:Р` Вам не пользовательский ввод чинить надо, а скорее базу `:D` Выставьте в ней кодировку UTF-8 для полей (collation по желанию, советую `utf8_bin`, но протестируйте на своих нуждах, прежде чем принимать решение).

Answer (score 1):

удалить конкретно эти символы так:

```
str = ' © ™'
a = str.tr('','').tr('©','').tr('™','')
b = str.gsub(/[\u{1F609}\u2122\u00A9]/,'')
```

или если оставить только русские/английские буквы + цифры и пробелы то вот так

```
a = str.gsub(/[^\p{L}\s\d]/,'')
```

удалить символы, чтобы твоя строка записалась в ДБ mysql UTF-8
при utf8_general_ci вот так:

```
c = str.gsub(/[\u{10000}-\u{FFFFF}]/,'')
```